# What are some good alternatives to SoundManager2?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, audio, soundmanager2

Soundmanager2 is a fine app, but the code is very hard to work with. It looks like it's been written by someone intentionally trying to obfuscate their code, and trying to be too clever. What are some worthwhile alternatives to Soundmanager2?

Some features to match:

- Transparent HTML5 audio handling
- Flash-driven audio for streaming via RTMP and mp3s as they download
- Simple integration
- Load and play files dynamically
- Events triggered during loading, playback, stopping, etc.

Comment: I don't agree that Soundmanager2 is hard to work with, or that the source code is "obfuscated". Are you sure you weren't reading the minified .js file? There is a non-minified and in my opinion very readable version, with comments, in the download. And the documentation is also very good, so I would not say it is hard to work with: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/

Comment: its total crap, I agree. Just run a test suite over all browsers and more important : real devices. It just doesn't work as they say.

Comment: Same here, after working with Soundmanager2  I just began to search for alternatives, and I landed on this page. It works, but as the OP said ... it's a sad code to look at.

Answer (score 5):

SoundManager2 is more than a simple audio player. I find it can be extremely powerful and the documentation is great! I guess some people mistaken soundManager2 from let's say jplayer. soundManager2 is more of an audio engine than a audio player. It provides all the necessary apis to use it effectively. While jplayer(or similar solutions) is more of a out-of-the-box solution.

I tried a tone of different html5 / flash fallback audio players and tbh soundManager2 was the only right one. since I wanted to control all the styling and markup. Other players that are easier to integrate / 'simpler' are harder to control and expand.

Try looking at the docs instead of the code. They provide methods you need to use it.

Comment: the only problem with that thing is : it's totally unpredictable and unstable ! We're embedded this into mobile application studio two years ago and it has gotten worse and worse.  If you want another comment on this : stay away if you need something solid. We are experts and tried really hard to get it running but again, its a total fail. It works in the most browsers but on mobile (as exposed) you will enter a hell of random bugs, not even fixable given their code quality.

Comment: @mc007 I haven't used SoundManager since then, and never used it on mobile. I didn't like it's codebase either, there are better solutions available on github.

Comment: Good comments chaps. I've decided to try an alternative to soundmanager2 too. Can you point me in the right direction of a suitable alternative please? :) What did you end up using? Thanks

Comment: @mc007 yeah there's no iOS (and some android) unlock.. that's why I've implemented my own audio world... when someone is interested in my player module tell me and I put it on github for you..

Comment: @Daniel Could you mention any of those solutions on github please?